# Is there a way to play a sound by specifying the frequency in Hz instead of musical note in SION?

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, synthesizer

I have been searching for ways to produce sound in as3 and found SION: https://sites.google.com/site/sioncenter/

Seems great, but I have one issue: I need to play tones at specific frequencies. The only options I find to play sounds is by specifying the frequency as musical notes (a, b, c, etc), but I need to play sounds specifying the frequency in Hz (30Hz, 100Hz, etc).

Is there a way to do this in SION?

If not, is there an alternative to SION? I need a sine wave generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need SION for that. You can do it with the Sound class.

Here's a tutorial that shows exactly how to do it:
http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=2669